# Error while Trying to access HBase through Java

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to write data to HBase through Java.Here is the code i am using:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configurable;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;


public class MyLittleHBaseClient 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        HBaseConfiguration config = new HBaseConfiguration();
        HTable table = new HTable(config, "myLittleHBaseTable");
        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"),
        Bytes.toBytes("Some Value"));
        table.put(p);
    }
}
```

I tried putting `conf.set("hbase.master","localhost:51310")` where 51310 is where my Hbase master server runs.My region servers are located at `"localhost:13184"`.This code above is very similar to what i found on internet the only thing being `HBaseConfiguration.create()` says "*No such method*".
The error encountered is org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Timed out trying to locate root region. My IDE is oracle Jdeveloper.I have added all the jar files and jps shows all servers running fine.I dont know what i am doing wrong.All the examples on internet show `HBaseConfiguration.create()` in their codes.I have used Hbase-0.90.4

Answer (score 0):

A few changes to your code should get it running.

Change the following:

```
 HBaseConfiguration config = new HBaseConfiguration();
```

to:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
```

If you're connecting to localhost, then just set the value for `hbase.master` as you've mentioned above. If you're connecting to a remote HBase store, then set the following:

```
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","<host name>")
```

and this

```
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","<client port used by zookeeper>")
```

and finally add

```
conf.set("hbase.master","<host name>:<port>")
```

For the first step, set an appropriate hostname in your hosts file (/etc/hosts in linux) and set it to the ip address of your machine. Now, give that hostname as the value for zookeeper quorum.This step is important because **HBase recognises only hostnames and not ip addresses**.

For the second step, find out the client port used by zookeeper by inspecting the configuration files under **/hbase/conf** directory

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to a remote system you cn use this code for configuration 

`config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", args[0]);// ip of hbase server(remote)
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", args[1]);// portno : 2181 default`

Edit the conf/regionservers file in hbase directory to add the Hbase server (Remote) in it 
(I did this and didnt need to edit the etc/hosts to get a hbase server in my office network)
i.e. after editing regionservers will look like

localhost
ip address of the remote hbase server

eg
localhost
10.132.258.366